# storing JSON columns in MySql is slowing down my Database searching

Tags: mysql

I am storing JSON String in my database in JSON column type, and I also have an Index column, I mean my table looks something like this

- Column 1 : ID (int,AI,Index)
- Column 2: String (JSON Type)

I have above 2000 records in my table, and it is taking more than 10 seconds when selecting records from it !!
my query is

```
select * from table where id = ""
```

Does  something relating to JSON type fields affect performance? Does anyone have suggestions to improve the performance of my database?

Comment: JSON is stored in a binary format, so it has to format it when returning it in the query.

Comment: That query shouldn't even return anything, unless you have a row with `id = 0`.

Comment: actually I didn't mention the ID, but of course, I do in my real query

Comment: why use quotes on ID? it's an int not character.  the engine has to cast it when you use quotes.  a small overhead.

Comment: But you're just selecting a single row? How big is the JSON object?

Comment: yes, you are right, it is not taking that time when selecting a single row, but when selecting multiple actually (like when it returns 100 records), but even though!! I didn't expect this delay!! does the size of the JSON object affect the performance too??

Comment: You should use `id = 1` instead off `id = "1"` for example.. if you qoute the id column MySQL can't use the index.

Comment: taking into consideration that my table may get more records, will it be slower then ?? !! thank you @Barmar

Comment: @RaymondNijland I am using a real integer value, just by mistake in the comment I Used String ,thank you

Comment: @Programmer The size of the JSON affects performance because it has to format it into a string, and formatting a bigger object takes more time. So the performance will depend on the size of the object and the number of rows being returned. Although 10 seconds seems pretty extreme unless it's enormous.